# Is it possible to emulate Mac Osx Finder search highlight in HTML + CSS?

Tags: css, macos, finder, search

Mac OSX Finder has a search feature that darkens everything but the part that matches.

[image]
<sub>(source: [justaddwater.dk](http://justaddwater.dk/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/mac-osx-finder-search-feature-spotlight.png))</sub>

Is there a way to emulate it via CSS? I was thinking about adding a semi-transparent black div with opacity 50. But how then do I cut a hole in it?? and possibly make the edge fuzzy?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Expose](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/expose/index.html) jquery plugin from the [jQuery TOOLS](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/index.html) collection.  I think it will accomplish exactly what you are looking for.  They even have a demo of [styling the mask with a background image](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/expose/styling.html).

Comment: Very interesting. I was not aware of that! It will do 80-90% of the work.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the irregular shapes, you're probably looking for an image. And due to the need for varying levels of transparency, you probably want a .png that would just be stuck over the selected item.

Good question, one way would be to have a "selected" png that had the glowing circle cover the selected one, and a different just dark png cover everything else.

EDIT: But you would probably want to use a library like jquery rather than coding everything from scrath your self, as to not reinvent the wheel and save TONS of time :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe a PNG image will work, a square with hole